# Javascript with react problems in alerts and making changes

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
    const boxs = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
    let turn = "X"; // X always starts
    boxs.forEach(box => {
    box.addEventListener('click', function() {
        alert('You clicked on ');
        box.innerHTML = turn;
        if (turn ==="X") {
    turn = "O";
        }
        else {
    turn = "X";
        }

    } );
    } );

    return (
    <>
    <h1 className="header">Have Fun!</h1>
    <div className="Board">
        <div className="item"></div>
        <div className="item"></div>
        <div className="item"></div>
        <div className="item"></div>
        <div className="item"></div>
        <div className="item"></div>
        <div className="item"></div>
        <div className="item"></div>
        <div className="item"></div>
    </div>
    </>
    );
}

export default App;
```

in App.js And in App.css i am using :

```
.header {
    text-align: center;
}

.Board {
    width: 550px;
    height: 550px;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-column-gap: 12px;
    grid-row-gap: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: aqua;
}

.item {
    /* width: 133px;
    height: 133px; */
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 34px;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.item:hover {
    background-color: #00c0a3;
}
```

When I run it, it does not show me an error but also it does not alert and write X or O.

Comment: You are mixing React and vanilla JS, that's why you are getting unexpected results. [Have a look at the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)!

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use a state to store the items and the current turn:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';

const initialItems = [ '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '' ]

function App() {

  const [turn, setTurn] = useState('X');
  const [items, setItems] = useState(initialItems);

  const handleClick = (idx) => {
    setItems((oldItems) => {
        oldItems[idx] = turn;
        return oldItems;
    })
    setTurn((oldTurn) => oldTurn === 'X' ? 'O' : 'X')
    alert('You clicked on ' + idx)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1 className='header'>Have Fun!</h1>
      <div className='Board'>
        {items.map((item, idx) => {
            return <div key={idx} className='item' onClick={() => handleClick(idx)}>{item}</div>
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```